# Meteor Cordova/Phonegap Local Assets

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, local-storage, cordova-plugins

I believe when building through meteor, the assets in the public folder should be saved with the app?

But upon looking through my build folder,

```
ROOTFOLDER/.meteor/cordova-build/platforms/android/assets/www/application/app/
```

Not all the assets has been included in there.

So my question is how do I make sure that all the assets will be in there and secondly how do I access those assets? Because I would like my app to still display those assets even when its offline.

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, is there a trend as to what assets aren't included, such as images are included but not videos?

Comment: Not really. Every time I perform the build it is always different.